# How do I upload the following described app in appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed an iOS app which is accessable only under VPN connection using CISCO AnyConnect app. If I didn't connect the VPN, my app does not work. Can I upload this app in appstore? How the apple team will access this app while testing?

Comment: 2 things: either this app is usable by anyone, thus needs to be on the app store and Apple team may be able to connect to it by creating an account or connecting to credentials you gave them OR this app is meant for companies and then you should start to think about Enterprise Distribution.

Comment: Actually this app is usuable by a orgaization. Only the employee of that organization will use this app for their internal purpose.

Comment: Then you shouldnt go through the App store. Try to look at other deployment methods (Ad Hoc or Enterprise) that does not require a validation by Apple teams and are more fitting your needs